# Does the SharePoint Site Collection Audit Log count against the site collection quota?

Tags: storage, quota

Does the SharePoint Site Collection Audit Log count against the site collection quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I've seen.  The audit log is a separate database in the SQL server to track that information.